# Problems subscribing to a room (socket) with Socket.IO-Client-Swift and Swift, Sails.js on the Server

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, socket.io, sails.js

On Swift, I use

```
socket.on("test") {data, ack in
    print(data)
}
```

In order to subscribe to a room (socket) on my Sails.js API.

When I broadcast a message from the server, with

```
sails.sockets.broadcast('test', { text : 'ok' })
```

the `socket.on` handler is never called. 
However, if I set "log" TRUE to config when connecting my socket.io client from swift, in Socket-IO logs the message arrives.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually, I found my mistake:

The whole process I did is right:
(The request to join the room is done by the server, with `sails.sockets.join`)

Wrong thing was using `socket.on` with the `ROOM NAME` parameter.

I will explain it better, for others having same problem:

1. From Swift you should subscribe by making a websocket request to an endpoint on the server that accepts websocket requests (GET, POST, PUT). For example, you can make a POST request, passing in the room name into the body.

   ```swift
   socket.emitWithAck("post", [
       "room": "testroom",
       "url": "/api/v1.0/roomsubscribing"
   ]).timingOut(after: 0) {data in
       print("Server responded with \(data)")
   }
   ```
2. On server side, inside the room-subscribing endpoint, you should have the following code:

   ```swift
   roomSubscribing: function(req, res) {
       if (!req.isSocket) {
         return res.badRequest();
       }

       sails.sockets.join(req, req.params('room'), function(err) {
         if (err) {
           return res.serverError(err);
         }
       }); 
    }
   ```
3. When the server want to broadcast some data to subscribers of the "testroom" room, the following code must be used:

   ```swift
   sails.sockets.broadcast('testroom', { message: 'testmessage' }
   ```

Now on the swift's side you must use:

```swift
socket.on("message") { data, ack in
    print(data)
}
```

in order to get the message handler to work. I thought you should use room name, instead you should use the KEY of the KEY/VALUE entry you used in your server when you broadcasted the data (in this case, "message").

Answer (score 1):

I only have a small amount of experience with sockets, but in case nobody else answers...

I think you are missing step one of the three step socket process:

1. A client sends a message to the server asking to subscribe to a particular room.
2. The client sets up a `socket.on` to handle particular events from that room.
3. The server broadcasts an event in a particular room. All subscribers/clients with a `.on` for that particular event will react.

I could be wrong, but it sounds from your description like you missed step one. Your client has to send a message with `io.socket`, something like [here](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/web-sockets/socket-client/io-socket-get), then your server has to use the socket request to have them join the room, something like in the example [here](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/web-sockets/sails-sockets/join).

(the presence of log data without the `socket.on` firing would seem to confirm that the event was broadcast in the room, but that client was not subscribed)

Good luck!